# Salvar checkbox marcados em um array!

Tags: php, html

Eu quero que, ao selecionar vários checkbox, esses valores sejam salvos em um array, para que depois ele seja salvo no banco de dados. Se eu deixar os checkbox com o mesmo id, como segue:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label style="margin-bottom: 10px"> Dias disponíveis 
          </label><br />
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="dias" id="dias" 
value="Segunda-Feira">  Segunda-Feira</label><br />
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="dias" id="dias" 
value="Terça-Feira">  Terça-Feira</label><br />
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="dias" id="dias" 
value="Quarta-Feira">  Quarta-Feira</label><br />
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="dias" id="dias" 
value="Quinta-Feira">  Quinta-Feira</label><br />
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="dias" id="dias" 
value="Sexta-Feira">  Sexta-Feira</label>
          </div>
```

O php já entende e coloca as opções marcadas no array diretamente após o submit usando:

```
$chgeckboxes = $_POST['checkbox'];
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Não coloque ids com o mesmo nome em uma página. coloque classes.

Comment: Usando classes o php entende da mesma forma e salva os valores no array?

Comment: Não, não use `id` repetidos, isso não faz sentido. Basta você adicionar `[]` ao `name` dos campos, fazendo `name="dias[]"`. Desta forma, o PHP receberá um *array* com os dias selecionados.

Comment: Entendi, ai posso tirar os ids de todos os cheboxs?

Comment: Sim, pode e deve.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, vou tentar fazer dessa forma!!

Comment: Arthur, só de haver um id, não é certo colocar vários ids com mesmo nome em uma página. Isso se faz com class, porque o id é único.

Comment: Nesse caso não precisa do id.

Comment: Entendido, nunca mais usar ids com mesmo nome, agradeço demais a ajuda!!

Comment: @ArthurOliveira quando você seleciona os checkbox e da o submit, o PHP já coloca os valores num array, e isso nao ta certo ? nao entendi direito sua duvida.

Comment: A minha dúvida era se estava certo isso

Answer (score 0):

**Como já dito, não se deve usar elementos com mesmo id em um documento.**

No seu caso o correto é usar um par de colchetes `[]` ao final do atributo name `name="dias[]"`. Dessa forma os elementos do mesmo nome são tratados como um array.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post"> 
<div class="form-group">
    <label style="margin-bottom: 10px"> Dias disponíveis 
    </label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="Segunda-Feira">  Segunda-Feira</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="Terça-Feira">  Terça-Feira</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="Quarta-Feira">  Quarta-Feira</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="Quinta-Feira">  Quinta-Feira</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="Sexta-Feira">  Sexta-Feira</label>
    <input type="submit">
</div>
</form>
```

**E no PHP**

```
if(!empty($_POST['dias']) && count($_POST['dias']) ){
   $chgeckboxes = $_POST['dias'];
   //print_r($chgeckboxes);


}
```